# How to create rest API GET method in php using multiple filter

Tags: php

I have created a rest API GET method in php using a parameter id. http://localhost:8012/REST-API/items/expenses?id=2. This is working fine but I want get data using http://localhost:8012/REST-API/items/expenses?id=2&year=2022. I am new to php and tried all possibilities but not getting proper response. Here is the code below

### Expenses.php inside /class file

```
<?php
class Expenses{   
    private $expensesTable = "expenses";      
    public $id;
    public $month;
    private $amount;
    public $year;
    
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }   

    function expenses(){    
        if($this->year) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$this->expensesTable." WHERE year = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $this->year);                    
        } 
        else if($this->id) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$this->expensesTable." WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $this->id);                  
        }
        else if($this->id && $this->year) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$this->expensesTable." WHERE id = ? AND year= ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $this->id,$this->year);                  
        }

        else {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$this->expensesTable);        
        }       
        $stmt->execute();           
        $result = $stmt->get_result();      
        return $result; 
    }
}
?>
```

### readexpenses.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

include_once '../config/Database.php';
include_once '../class/Expenses.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
 
$expenses = new Expenses($db);

$expenses->id = (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '0';
$expenses->year = (isset($_GET['year']) && $_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : '0';
$expenses->extra = (isset($_GET['month']) && $_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month'] : '0';

$result = $expenses->expenses();

if($result->num_rows > 0){    
    $itemRecords=array();
    $itemRecords["expenses"]=array(); 
    while ($expense = $result->fetch_assoc()) {     
        extract($expense); 
        $itemDetails=array(
            "id" => $id,
            "month" => $month,
            "amount" => $amount,
            "year" => $year
        ); 
       array_push($itemRecords["expenses"], $itemDetails);
    }    
    http_response_code(200);     
    echo json_encode($itemRecords);
}else{     
    http_response_code(404);     
    echo json_encode(
        array("message" => "No item found.")
    );
}
```

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^read$ read.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^read/([0-9_-]*)$ read.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^create$ create.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^update$ update.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^delete$ delete.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^expenses$ readexpenses.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^expenses/([0-9_-]*)$ readexpenses.php?year=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^expenses/([0-9_-]*)$ readexpenses.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^expenses/([0-9_-]*)$ readexpenses.php?id=$1&year=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: That last three rules are wrong, how you will differentiate between an `id` and a `year`? is the year 4 digits only? It's the id more that 4 digits? why you dont change the url to something like: `expenses/id/123456` and `expenses/year/2022` and when both are present just `expenses/123456/2022`, also you are allowing the `-` character just use: `[0-9]+` to only get numbers

Comment: As per your question id will be from 1 to 4 digit and year will be 4 digit always. so the final rule will be RewriteRule ^expenses/([0-9]+)$ readexpenses.php/year/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^expenses/([0-9]+)$ readexpenses.php/id/$1 [NC,L]  and in browser  http://localhost:8012/REST-API/items/expenses/year/2021 but its showing "url not found"

Comment: Just answered, let me know if it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment he last three rules are wrong:

```
RewriteRule ^expenses/([0-9_-]*)$ readexpenses.php?year=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^expenses/([0-9_-]*)$ readexpenses.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^expenses/([0-9_-]*)$ readexpenses.php?id=$1&year=$2 [NC,L]
```

What happens in this url? `http://example.com/expenses/2012` how do you detect that is an `id` or `year`?

I suggest to use this scheme:

```
http://example.com/expenses/id/2012   -> readexpenses.php?id=2012
http://example.com/expenses/year/2022 -> readexpenses.php?year=2022
http://example.com/expenses/2012/2022 -> readexpenses.php?id=2012&year=2022
```

So the `.htaccess` file will be: (just changed the last three rules)

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^read$ read.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^read/([0-9_-]*)$ read.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^create$ create.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^update$ update.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^delete$ delete.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^expenses$ readexpenses.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^expenses/year/([0-9]+)$ readexpenses.php?year=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^expenses/id/([0-9]+)$ readexpenses.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^expenses/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ readexpenses.php?id=$1&year=$2 [NC,L]
```

Online tests:

I have tested and it works in every case [`id/year`](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=974c078d-c85c-4be9-acbc-c0cd0645a02c), [`id`](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=aad47dbe-df05-48ff-8d3a-93f104a54325) and [`year`](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=e536a834-2191-4067-b4a4-7b084bef3913), bellow you can see that it passes for that url

Also you should change your php conditions

```
if ($this->id && $this->year) {
  //..
} else if ($this->id) {
  //..
} else if ($this->year) {
  //..
} else {
  //..
}
```

Without this change it will never reach when id and year and setted

Comment: After modification showing server error

Comment: I added online tests in the asnwer, it's showing 500 server error?